# How many pants decompositions for a given surface with a fixed hyperbolic metric?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Given a closed surface of genus $g\geq 2$ and a fixed hyperbolic metric on it, how many pants decompositions exist for that surface?

I tend to believe that it is finite ? For example, if we take a surface of genus 2, and fix a hyperbolic metric on it, then aren't there exactly two ways of cutting it into two pants? I know one can give ( Dehn ) twists along a geodesic which we cut, but would that not change the metric?

Thanks!

Comment: The surface of genus two has only two pants decompositions _up to homeomorphism_.  It has infinitely many pants decompositions _up to isotopy_.  It is important to understand the difference between these two concepts.  Check out the Wikipedia pages!

The hyperbolic metric doesn't effect the above two statements.

Comment: Perhaps the other fact to mention is that, given any *topological* pants decomposition (defined up to isotopy), you can replace the cutting curves by geodesic representatives.  In this sense, you can make any decomposition you like compatible with the metric.

Comment: which wikipidea page are you talking about ? I searched it but apparently I didnt find any detailed treatment of it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy is the first hit on google for the search "isotopy".  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isotopy.html is the third hit.  Hmmm.  Perhaps you would be better off reading the material in Rolfsen's book on curves in the two-torus (which has pictures and exercises). 

Answer (score 3):

If the surface is not a pair of pants, there are *infinitely* many different isotopy classes of pants decompositions (which, as mentioned in the comments, can be made compatible with a constant curvature metric).

They are all "connected" by a finite sequence of "moves".  The collection of the isotopy classes (thought of as 0-cells), connected by edges (1-cells) if they are related by the aforementioned moves, and with 2-cells added according to relations among the moves forms a 2-complex that Hatcher has shown to be simply connected.  See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906084v1.pdf) for precise definitions and the proof.

On the other hand, the mapping class group acts on the 1-skeleton of this complex (see [here](http://www.math.kit.edu/iag3/~wolf/media/wolf-the-action-of-the-mapping-class-group-on-the-pants-complex.pdf)), and the quotient is a finite graph. So there are *finitely* many homeomorphism classes of pants decompositions.

As far as I can tell, the precise number of homeomorphism classes of pants decompositions is not presently known. See [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Eisenberg.pdf) for a lower bound however.

Comment: The paper of Hatcher referred to was published (in slightly modified form) as Section 2 of a paper by Pierre Lochak, Leila Schneps, and myself: "On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups", J. reine angew. Math. 521 (2000), 1-24. The proof of the result mentioned in Sean Lawton's answer was based heavily on parts of an earlier paper of Bill Thurston and myself.